# Open putty ssh connection over SOCKS5 proxy via command line

Tags: windows, ssh, proxy, putty

I tried to open putty ssh connection over SOCKS5 proxy via command line.

```
putty.exe -P port -pw password username@host -nc proxyhost:proxyport
```

This command doesn't work and I think it is incorrect. I tried a lot of variants of this command, but putty user manual doesn't contain necessary information.

I tried to connect to my host throw putty UI and it works fine.

For openSSH similar command looks

```
ssh -o "ProxyCommand=nc -x proxyhost:proxyport %h %p" -p port username@host
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I were you I would create a "Saved Session" with Putty and launch it via command line:

`putty.exe -load session_name`

It will be easier to create a "Saved Session" via the PuTTY interface than toying around with the command line. And it seems like you already have it working through the PuTTY interface.

Comment: In additional putty stores its configuration on registry and it is not convenient to manipulate with registry, because you need administrator privileges. I found patched [putty](http://jakub.kotrla.net/putty/) which stores its configuration in files.

Answer (score 2):

Even though this is an old thread I would like to add my two cents, as I found it hard to gather all the information necessary to set up a working `ssh` connection over a SOCKS-5 proxy using `putty` command line and this thread showed up in my result list.

## TL;DR

It is currently not possible (as of putty `v0.74`) to route `ssh` traffic over a SOCKS-5 proxy using `putty` or `plink` as the proxy-command on the command line. You have to use an alternative like [ncat](https://nmap.org/ncat/) for windows, e.g.:

```
putty -p <targetport> -proxycmd "ncat.exe --proxy-type socks5 --proxy <proxyhost>:<proxyport> <targethost> <targetport>" <targethost>
```

## Details

The `putty` GUI allows the configuration of an SOCKS-5 proxy, see [putty documentation](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/0.74/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-proxy-type).

As correctly stated in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37181741/1994888),  by BlakBat this configuration can be called via command line using the `-load` argument.

The command line argument `-proxycmd` triggers the use of a so called 'local' proxy connection (see the [putty documentation again](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/0.74/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-cmdline)):

```
> 3.8.3.24 -proxycmd: specify a **local** proxy command
```

The local proxy command is a command issued on the local machine, that will handle the proxy connection (see [the documentation about proxy types](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/0.74/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-proxy-type)). [ncat](https://nmap.org/ncat/) is such a command and it is able to interact with a SOCKS-5 proxy.

Finally, it is tempting to use `plink`/`putty` as the proxy command to avoid the use of multiple tools.
Putty [claims](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/0.74/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-cmdline) to provide an alternative to the `netcat` utility via the `-nc` argument, however the [putty documentation](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/0.74/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-proxy-type) states:

> If you want your local proxy command to make a secondary SSH connection to a proxy host and then tunnel the primary connection over that, you might well want the -nc command-line option in Plink.

If you try to use the `-nc` argument to open a SOCKS-5 connection your SOCKS server log might show something like this:

```
sockd[1234]: info: block(1): tcp/accept ]: 1.2.3.4.4711 1.2.3.5.1080: error after reading 1 byte in 0 seconds: unknown SOCKS version 83 in client request
```

This is an indication that an attempt was made to open an SSH session to the SOCKS-5 server.

So, unfortunately, to my knowledge your only chance is to use `putty` along with a netcat-like tool to establish a proxied SSH connection using an SOCKS-5 proxy.

Answer (score 1):

Simple,

```
putty -D 8080 <user_id>@<server_name> -pw <password>
```